# By-name repeated parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming, variadic-functions, lazy-evaluation

How to pass by-name repeated parameters in Scala?

The following code fails to work:

```
scala> def foo(s: (=> String)*) = {
<console>:1: error: no by-name parameter type allowed here
       def foo(s: (=> String)*) = {
                   ^
```

Is there any other way I could pass a variable number of by name parameters to the method?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618891/using-lazy-evaluation-functions-in-varargs

Comment: What is the reason you want to use by-name parameters in this case? Perhaps we can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't very pretty but it allows you to pass byname parameters varargs style

```
def printAndReturn(s: String) = {
  println(s)
  s
}

def foo(s: (Unit => String)*) {
  println("\nIn foo")
  s foreach {_()}  // Or whatever you want ...
}

foo()

foo((Unit) => printAndReturn("f1"),
    (Unit) => printAndReturn("f2"))
```

This produces

In foo

In foo
f1
f2

Comment: It's certainly not pleasant to look at nor to write. And I continue to encourage people to distinguish by-name parameters (that are *implemented* using a thunk but are otherwise logically distinct) and function values used as arguments. Likewise for methods and functions.

Comment: I think Randall's comments are fair, the above could be perhaps improved with a helper function to wrap / pre-process the arguments, for example:
  def deferred(block: => String) = () => block
with foo altered to:
  def foo(s: (() => String)*)
giving, for example:
foo(deferred {val a = "apples"; "Green "+apples}, 
    deferred {"Pears"})

Answer (score 11):

Repeated by-name parameters are not currently supported.

Answer (score 2):

If struggling for nice syntax the goal can be achieved using implicits.

```
implicit def arg2func(arg: ⇒ Byname): (() => Byname) = () ⇒ arg

def foo(params: (() ⇒ Byname)*): Unit = {
    println("foo: not yet evaluated.")
    params.foreach(_())
}

def boo(params: Byname*): Unit = {
    println("boo: already evaluated")
}

foo(Byname(0), Byname(1), Byname(2))
println()
boo(Byname(3), Byname(4), Byname(5))

case class Byname(n: Int) {
    println(n)
}
```

That prints:

> foo: not yet evaluated.
>
> 0 1 2
>
> 3 4 5
>
> boo: already evaluated

Answer (score 0):

You can write `() => String` instead of Unit (it's the same thing anyway)

Comment: It really isn't "the same thing." The semantics and the syntax are different both for calling and for using them in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Randall Schulz on the good one-line answer.

I was looking for this possibility in order to make an INVARIANT tool that would run multiple asserts together. The solution I then came up with is to simply have 1..5 `apply` methods, since the number of varargs needed here is finite.

```
object INVARIANT {
  def apply = {}
  def apply( conds: => Boolean * ) = {    // DOES NOT COMPILE
    conds.foreach( assert(_) )
  }
}

object TestX extends App {

  class A {
    println("A body")
    INVARIANT( true )
  }

  class B extends A {
    println("B body")
    INVARIANT( true, false )  
  }

  new B
}
```

I posted this to show what I believe is a valid use case for varargs on 'by-name' variables. If there is a better name, please leave a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Scala 3:

```scala
scala> def f(i: => Int*): Int = i.sum
def f(i: => Int*): Int

scala> f(1, 2, 3)
val res0: Int = 6
```

Comment: However, all elements seem to be forced the moment the collection is referenced:
```
def fs(x: =>String*): String = x.head
fs({ println("1"); "1"}, {println("2"); "2"})
// gives:
1
2
res1: String = "1"
```