# Scala lazy evaluation and apply function

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I'm following a book's example to implement a Steam class using lazy evaluation in Scala.

```
sealed trait Stream[+A]
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
    def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
        lazy val head = hd
        lazy val tail = tl
        Cons(() => head, () => tail)
    }

    def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

    def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] = {
        if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
    }
}
```

Then I used a simple function to test if it's working

```
def printAndReturn: Int = {
    println("called")
    1
}
```

Then I construct Stream like the following:

```
    println(s"apply: ${
        Stream(
            printAndReturn,
            printAndReturn,
            printAndReturn,
            printAndReturn
        )
    }")
```

The output is like this:

```
called
called
called
called
apply: Cons(fpinscala.datastructures.Stream$$$Lambda$7/1170794006@e580929,fpinscala.datastructures.Stream$$$Lambda$8/1289479439@4c203ea1)
```

Then I constructed Stream using `cons`:

```
println(s"cons: ${
    cons(
        printAndReturn,
        cons(
            printAndReturn,
            cons(printAndReturn, Empty)
        )
    )
}")
```

The output is:

```
cons: Cons(fpinscala.datastructures.Stream$$$Lambda$7/1170794006@2133c8f8,fpinscala.datastructures.Stream$$$Lambda$8/1289479439@43a25848)
```

So here are two questions:

1. When constructing Stream using the apply function, all `printAndReturn` are evaluated. Is this because the recursive call to `apply(as.head, ...)` evaluates every head?
2. If the answer to the first question is true, then how do I change `apply` to make it not force evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.  If you put a breakpoint on the `println` you'll find that the method is actually being called when you first create the `Stream`.  The line `Stream(printAndReturn, ...` actually calls your method however many times you put it there.  Why?  Consider the type signatures for `cons` and `apply`:

   ```
   def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A]
   ```

   vs:

   ```
   def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A]
   ```

   Note that the definition for `cons` has its parameters marked as `=> A`.  This is a by-name parameter.  Declaring an input like this makes it lazy, delaying its evaluation until it is actually used.  Hence your `println` will never get called using `cons`.  Compare this to `apply`.  You're not using a by name parameter and therefore anything that gets passed in to that method will automatically get evaluated.
2. Unfortunately there isn't a super easy way as of now.   What you really want is something like `def apply[A](as: (=>A)*): Stream[A]` but unfortunately Scala does not support vararg by name parameters. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707186/by-name-repeated-parameters) for a few ideas on how to get around this.  One way is to just wrap your function calls when creating the Stream:

   ```
   Stream(
     () => printAndReturn,
     () => printAndReturn,
     () => printAndReturn,
     () => printAndReturn)
   ```

   Which will then delay the evaluation.

Comment: I see now. So the workaround you posted is passing a function that returns the to-be-evaluated function, so that even the () => func is evaluated, func itself is not. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

When you called

```
Stream(
            printAndReturn,
            printAndReturn,
            printAndReturn,
            printAndReturn
        )
```

the apply in the companion object was invoked. Looking at the parameter type of the apply, you would notice that it is strict. So the arguments will be evaluated first before being assigned to **as**. What **as** becomes is an Array of Ints

For 2, you can define apply as

```
def apply[A](as: (() => A)*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head(), apply(as.tail: _*))
```

and as was suggested above, you need to pass the arguments as thunks themselves as in

```
println(s"apply: ${Stream(
    () => printAndReturn,
    () => printAndReturn,
    () => printAndReturn,
    () => printAndReturn
  )}")
```