# Lazy evaluation, thunk and function closure in Scala

Tags: scala, closures, lazy-evaluation, thunk

```
case class Test[A](elem: () => A)

object Fun extends App {

  def test1(v: => Int): Test[Int] = Test(() => v)

  val a1 = test1({ println("hello"); 1 })
  val a2 = a1.elem() //echoes hello
  val a3 = a1.elem() //echoes hello

  def test2(v: => Int): Test[Int] = {
    lazy val y = v
    Test(() => y)
  }

  val b1 = test2({ println("hello"); 1 })
  val b2 = b1.elem() //echoes hello
  val b3 = b1.elem() //doesn't echo hello. Is function closure at work here?
}
```

Test is a case class that takes an object of type `Function0[A]` as constructor argument.

`test1` uses a non-strict parameter and returns an instance of `Test[Int]`.
when `a1` is created, it gets `elem = () => { println("hello"); 1 }`. And so it makes sense when *hello* gets printed twice while `a2` and `a3` are created by applying elem.

`test2` also uses a non-strict parameter and returns an instance of `Test[Int]`.
when `b1` is created, it gets `elem = () => y`. The `y` is unevaluated and is bound to the caller - `test2`. When `elem` is applied to create `b2`, through `elem()`, `y` gets evaluated (and thus prints *hello*) 
and then caches the result which is `1`. Subsequent call to `elem()` while creating `b3` uses the evaluated value. However since `y` is not local to `elem`, the only way all this can work is through closure.

Is that accurate?

Note: I have gone through the example posted here : [Scala lazy evaluation and apply function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258360/scala-lazy-evaluation-and-apply-function) but it isn't exactly what I am trying to understand

Answer (score 2):

You can see the implementation of captured elements using `scalac -Vprint:_`.

In this case,

```
    def test2(v: Function0): Test = {
      lazy <artifact> val y$lzy: scala.runtime.LazyInt = new scala.runtime.LazyInt();
      new Test({
        (() => Fun.this.$anonfun$test2$1(y$lzy, v))
      })
    };
```

The lazy local becomes heap-allocated, with a reference passed into the closure.