# Creating a Stream out of a couple of elements lazily in Scala

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, scala-streams

Just for testing purposes I wanted to compute lazily 2 elements:

```
  Stream(
    { Thread.sleep(2000); 1 },
    { Thread.sleep(2000); 2 },
    Stream.empty[Int]
  ).foreach(println)
```

But running this code does not yield the desired result. The values seem to show up all at the same time in the output. The reason is that the `Stream()` constructor is taking an array that has to be computed eagerly. So to fix that, I had to resort to manually creating the thunks of the stream like this:

```
  (
    { Thread.sleep(2000); 1 } #::
    { Thread.sleep(2000); 2 } #::
    Stream.empty[Int]
  ).foreach(println)
```

which now works exactly as intended but is not particularly pretty.

Is there a cleaner and more convenient way of having something syntactically similar to `Stream(a, b, c)` but that evaluates the arguments lazily?

Thanks

Comment: It probably should be *syntactically similar* but "*semantically **not** equivalent*", because it's exactly the different semantics that you are after.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a special class that can hold by-name blocks that produce `A` together with a short helper method that helps instantiate this class:

```
class ByNameArg[+A](a: => A) {
  def unpack: A = a
}

/** Single lazy by-name argument wrapper */
def l[A](a: => A) = new ByNameArg(a)
```

then you can define the following factory method:

```
def lazyStreamInit[A](xs: ByNameArg[A]*): Stream[A] = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) {
    Stream.empty[A]
  } else {
    xs.head.unpack #:: lazyStreamInit(xs.tail: _*)
  }
}
```

It can be used with little syntactic overhead (you have just to prepend a single character `l` to each block that you pass in the vararg-list):

```
lazyStreamInit(
  l{ Thread.sleep(2000); 1 },
  l{ Thread.sleep(2000); 2 }
)
```

In contrast to usual `() => A`-workaround, this directly produces a `Stream[A]`, not a `Stream[() => A]`.

Getting rid of the `l` or `{ () => ... }` does not seem possible, because [repeated by-name arguments are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707186/by-name-repeated-parameters).

---

**Edit**

By "the usual `() => A`-workaround" I meant something like

```
Stream(
  { () => Thread.sleep(2000); 1 },
  { () => Thread.sleep(2000); 2 }
).map{ _() }.foreach(println)
```

Note that you have to append an additional `map`-step to make it a `Stream[A]`.

Answer (score 1):

This would require repeated by-name parameters which aren't currently supported (http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/repeated-byname.html, https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5787). They are available [in Dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/499), though.

You *could* use repeated `() => A`, but then you'd need to write

```
def makeStream[A](xs: (() => A)*) = ...

makeStream(
  { () => Thread.sleep(2000); 1 },
  { () => Thread.sleep(2000); 2 }
).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Prints `Main$$anon$1$$Lambda$132/1785210046@368239c8
Main$$anon$1$$Lambda$133/1552787810@9e89d68`. You probably want to `map{_()}`.

Comment: Oops. I meant to define a function `makeStream` which takes them, not to use `Stream.apply`.